# Why does a battery powered radio's volume go down as batteries age, even when the batteries' voltage is constant?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, voltage, batteries, radio

A set of batteries are used for a long period of time. Explain why the volume of a radio is low even though the voltage of the batteries is the same as when they were first bought.

Comment: Well what do you think? What specific issue are you having in answering this question?

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! This is a great site for physics questions and answers.  To keep the site great, we follow some simple rules about quality and clarity. First, please write meaningful titles. I edited the title of this post to make it more specific.

Answer (score 5):

It is true that the voltage (EMF) of a used battery could be close to the voltage of a fresh battery, when measured with a voltmeter. But a used battery can generate such voltage only when it is not loaded, i.e., when it does not supply any current or power. This is an open circuit voltage.

Once a used battery is connected to a load, like a radio, and the current starts flowing, the voltage would drop by a greater value than it would if the battery was fresh.

We can say that the efficiency of the used battery has decreased or its effective internal resistance has increased.

As the current flows in a circuit, consisting of a battery and a load, its open circuit voltage is divided between the load resistance and the internal resistance of the battery.

So, if the load resistance is fixed and the internal resistance of the battery has increased, the voltage applied to the load will decrease.

When the voltage applied to a load decreases, its effect on the operation of the load depends on the power supply inside the load.

Some loads may start drawing more current from the battery and thus preserve their power consumption, so their output power won't change. Of course, that could be done only, while the internal resistance of the battery is lower than the resistance of the load: beyond that point any attempt to draw more current from the battery will fail.

Other loads, perhaps, like your radio, will just draw lower current, consume lower power and will, correspondingly, have a reduced output power.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that the greater the sound volume, the greater the load on the battery and thus a still greater drop in the battery's voltage, but plus one for open circuit vs. closed circuit voltage.

Comment: @BillDOe "It might be worth mentioning that the greater the sound volume, the greater the load on the battery and thus a still greater drop in the battery's voltage". Absolutely, that's why I've mentioned that this tactics can work only so far - did not want to get into details (the answer was a bit too long already). Thanks for your comment.